# Having trouble Generating Wrapper function using Swig for C++ template

Tags: swig

I am trying to use swig to generate interface on some existing C++ methods. I am referring to the following link for practice to generate on c++ template methods

https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/swig/Examples/python/template/

**File : example.h**

```
// Some template definitions

template<class T> T max(T a, T b) { return  a>b ? a : b; }

template<class T> class vector {
  T *v;
  int sz;
 public:
  vector(int _sz) {
    v = new T[_sz];
    sz = _sz;
  }
  T &get(int index) {
    return v[index];
  }
  void set(int index, T &val) {
    v[index] = val;
  }
#ifdef SWIG
  %extend {
    T getitem(int index) {
      return $self->get(index);
    }
    void setitem(int index, T val) {
      $self->set(index,val);
    }
  }
#endif
};
```

**File : example.i**

```
%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

/* Let's just grab the original header file here */
%include "example.h"

/* Now instantiate some specific template declarations */

%template(maxint) max<int>;
%template(maxdouble) max<double>;
%template(vecint) vector<int>;
%template(vecdouble) vector<double>;
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension 
#name of module 
name  = "example"
  
#version of module 
version = "1.0"
  
# specify the name of the extension and source files 
# required to compile this 
ext_modules = Extension(name='_example',sources=["example.i","example.h"]) 
  
setup(name=name, 
      version=version, 
      ext_modules=[ext_modules])
```

## step 1: compile module

```
python setup.py build_ext
```

## step 2: install in the current directory

```
python setup.py install --install-platlib=.
```

**I am seeing the following errors as the output**

```
python setup.py build_ext
running build_ext
building '_example' extension
swigging example.i to example_wrap.c
swig -python -o example_wrap.c example.i
example.h:5: Warning 301: class keyword used, but not in C++ mode.
example.h:5: Error: Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon.
error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following in `setup.py` to pass the `-c++` option to SWIG.  Also remove `example.h` from sources or the compiler tries to compile the header.  It's already included in the generated file.

```
ext_modules = Extension(name='_example', sources=["example.i"], swig_opts=['-c++'])
```

Comment: Hi Mark , Thanks for the suggestion , After modifying the comments i was having some gc++ error with swig which i fixed . And the example . py got generated .

Comment: using a driver code for the example.py and try to run , I am hitting the following error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_example' which i am trying to fix . But thanks for helping me out